# Why does AdSense code not conform to Google page-speed insights requirements?

Tags: google-adsense, google-adsense-policies, google-pagespeed

I run my website through numerous of testing websites including Google page-speed insights. The problem is that Google AdSense code doesn't validate perfectly and for that reason, my score is no higher than 98%. This is what Google states:

> Consider Fixing:
>
> - Leverage browser caching
>     Setting an expiry date or a maximum age in the HTTP headers for static resources instructs the browser to load previously downloaded resources from local disk rather than over the network.
>     Leverage browser caching for the following cacheable resources:
>
>   - `http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/formats/templates.js` (60 minutes)
>   - `http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js` (60 minutes)
>   - `http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/osd.js` (60 minutes)
> - Minify JavaScript
>     Compacting JavaScript code can save many bytes of data and speed up downloading, parsing, and execution time.
>     Minify JavaScript for the following resources to reduce their size by 536B (2% reduction).
>
>   - Minifying `http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/…s/r20150409/r20150224/expansion_embed.js` could save 536B (2% reduction) after compression.

If I took off all advertisements, I would score 100%. The only way I could see me score 100% with AdSense is to make my webserver download their source code and modify it to comply with pagespeed insights but if I did that, then I'd get in trouble with AdSense as I'm then violating their policies.

Why should my site suffer the 2% if the problem is related to Google?

Comment: You worry too much. You are scoring a lot higher than I do right now. I have a new template, but have to modify some content pages that I would rather update first. The score is just an indication. It is not a test in high-school. There is no nun with a ruler. But there are places to hire one- but I digress. ;-)

Comment: I guess. Apparently google doesnt care at the moment since I'm actually getting more than a couple pennies today.

Comment: Me too brother. It takes a cr@p-l0@d of traffic to make money. Some days $.01 and others a few dollars. You have to get into at least 300 real visitors per day to start to make any money.

Comment: @closetnoc - I know that if site loads slow then it can increase bounce rate , Is there any other damage slow loading can? specially in SEO?

Comment: Very slow sites will not be placed first in the SERPs, however, that grade is on a curve where most any site should perform just fine. Even then, just poke around the net a bit and see how slow many sites that perform well load. Yes. Bounce rate is a factor, but sites that perform well can take double-digit seconds to load fully. This is what Google measures- the entire load time including 3rd party stuff. I have bounced because of load time. However, most people are fairly patient if they can get to the content and begin to read it. You would be surprised at what sites fail this simple test.

Comment: my site can easily load in 0.5 seconds without ads, but its the ads that cause the site loading to finish completely. Some ads make the site take as long as 6 seconds to load.

Answer (score 3):

You say that there are page speed **requirements** but they are actually **recommendations**, **guidelines**, and **best practices**.   Most of the time, you would do better to follow the advice, but there are times when the advice is inappropriate or not worth the effort.

You don't need to get a perfect score.   Any score about "80%" is probably *good enough*.  For search engine optimization purposes, I've found that Google doesn't penalize sites in any way as long as they load and render in under 3 seconds.   Further improvements can be good for users, but won't result in better rankings.    Load times of 3 to 7 seconds appear to cause users to turn away which can lower rankings.  Load times of greater than 7 seconds are actively penalized by Google.

Load times are generally measure until the "DOM Ready" event which is when the page is generally usable by the user.   Ads typically load asynchronously.  The page can be usable before the ads load and the ads shouldn't delay the DOM Ready event.

Google ignores the caching suggestions for AdSense ads because the ads are dynamic.   The JavaScript that writes the ads into your site is dynamic.  The ads can change with every refresh.   Caching could break this functionality.

As far as minimization goes, a 2% reduction isn't great savings.   In that case, it just isn't worth the effort of doing it.

If you want your site to make money with ads, you are going to have to accept the lower score.

Comment: I'm starting to learn that I need to tweak the server more because I did a test on a simulated dial-up connection with a max download speed of 5kbps and the page did not completely load.

Comment: Is it even possible to score an 80% with Google Ads? My site drops from a 90 to a 60 something with Ad Manager and AdSense. Another site drops from 80'ish to less than 40 with ads.